# change data for next input dynamically

Tags: r, shiny

i have two select input in my 
UI.R
    library(shiny)

```
ContextElements = c("choice1", "choice2", "choice3")
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

headerPanel(""),

sidebarPanel(
  h4("test for selectize input"),

 selectizeInput(inputId = "firstAxe", label = h4("First Axe"),  
               choices=ContextElements, selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE,
               options = NULL),
 hr(),

 selectizeInput(inputId = "twoAxe", label = h4("Second Axe"),  
               choices=NULL, selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE,
               options = NULL)
),
mainPanel(
  )
))
```

i want that the next selectizeinput choices ("twoAxe") to be filled dynamically with the remained choices drom the first one, that's mean if i choosed the first choice if the first one, the second choices will be choice2 and choice3

Thanks

Comment: Without the full code to work with, I'd imagine you could do this on the server.R side, with some sort of reactive that includes something to the effect of `ContextElements_new <- ContextElements[!(ContextElements %in% input$firstAxe)]` But this is just a guess and would require a bit of tinkering. Someone may be able to provide a better answer. Or you could include the reproducible code for the server.R and UI.r and a better/correct solution could come of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in `server.r` using `updateSelectizeInput` . Lets assume that `ContextElements` is available to the server - either defined in `global.r` or in both `server.r` and `ui.r`. Then this should work:

```
observe({

    input$firstAxe   # makes the second selectize change when the first one does

    updateSelectizeInput({session, inputId="twoAxe",
         choices=as.list( ContextElements[!ContextElements %in% input$firstAxe] )  })
})
```

As you change you choice in `firstAxe` you should see the choices in `twoAxe` respond.

Comment: it should be updateSelectizeInput(..) rather than updateSelectizeInput({..})